# How to fix - Syntax error in OPEN statement at (1)?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I'm trying to write data to binary file from ionosphere model without any special symbols, but now i get 2C000000 (6.165713e-44) - value, that spoil my research. I'm try to fix that, by changing of open command, i'm try add fileopt parameter, but get error.
I'm compile this by gfortran

```
open(unit = 7,file="iri2016.bin",fileopt = 'NOPAD',
 & form = "unformatted",recl = 44)
```

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. You will get more attention.

Comment: If you want to help with the problem with wrong values in your model, ask a new question and show your code. See [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fileopt=` specifier is not standard Fortran. It is also not needed, do not use it.

Use either the direct unformatted or stream unformatted access.